# Подскажите что лучше изучать CSS Grid, bootstrap или flexbox

Tags: css, bootstrap, flexbox, css-grid

Подскажите что лучше изучать CSS Grid, bootstrap или flexbox
что более удобнее для пользования , и что более лучше для создания сайтов

Comment: если изучить все три, то будет вообще идеально

Comment: это понятно, насколько я понял , начать с flexbox , потом  CSS Grid чтобы потом можно было вместе изучить, ну и если силы остануться то bootstrap , но в bootstrap  мне не нравиться , что нужно добавлять костыли вечно

Comment: Пользователю совершенно все равно на чем и как написан сайт, главное чтобы все было красиво и удобно. А что "более лучше" разработчик решает для конкретной задачи сам.

Comment: Текущий релиз bootstrap на float,новый на flexbox,grid еще не во всех браузерах поддерживается.Начните с основ css.

Comment: У каждого есть плюсы и минусы потому кого-то выделить отдельно нет смысла. Как писал (писала) в первом комментарии @diraria - если все три выучить будет вполне нормально.

Comment: Судя только по тому как вы задаете вопрос - вам нужно изучать азы верстки. И это ни что лучше, а знать надо, как минимум иметь представление, а уж с чего начнете, смотрите сами. Лепить бутстрап не зная верстки не самый лучший вариант. Не зная инлайн блоков лепить флексы, не тоже не очень хорошо. Гриды знать хорошо, но после всего остального уже, т к они только начинают более или менее поддерживаться.

Answer (score 3):

Стоит сразу отметить,что Flexbox и CSS Grid — это специальные модули CSS. А Bootstrap — фреймворк, который в основном используется для адаптация к мобильным устройствам.  На начальном этапе вам необходимо достаточно хорошо разобраться с HTML и CSS. В дальнейшем стандартно рекомендуется начать с изучения фреймворка Bootstrap. Затем освоить другие фреймворки. После чего Вы сможете подобрать необходимый фреймворк, который будет наиболее удобен для вас и для конкретных целей. Так же у Вас появятся свои готовые решения на базе освоенного материала и полученного опыта.  Если просто ответит на Ваш вопрос порядок следующий:

1. HTML
2. CSS в общем
3. Flexbox
4. CSS Grid
5. Bootstrap
6. Другие фреймворки.

Answer (score 2):

CSS Grid, Flexbox, Bootstrap друг друга не заменяют, у них разное назначение, хотя некоторые элементы можно сделать сразу на нескольких из них.

Я рекомендую для начала поверхностно изучить понять что каждая из этих технологий делает. А потом можно будет изучать более подробно сами технологии.

Последовательность предлагаю такую.

1. Flexbox (на первом месте, так как сейчас он реально много где используется, и многие вещи без него не сделать, очень удобен).
2. CSS Grid
3. Bootstrap (на последнем месте так как первые два это модули CSS, то есть основа, а Bootstrap это Framework).

Теперь кратко что делает каждая из технологий.

1. Flexbox - контейнер для последовательности элементов, списков (таблицы на нём обычно не делают).
2. CSS Grid - позволяет делать шаблоны (layout) страницы табличным методом, современная и мощная технология.
3. Bootstrap - фреймворк для создания адаптивных страниц корректно и красиво отображающихся на устройствах с разным размером экрана: мобильники, планшеты, ПК. Так же имеет в себе много (библиотека) различных компонентов страницы.